# Update Opportunity Stage when Quote Status is Changed

Tags: workflow, opportunity, quote

Is there a non code way to solve this?

I need the the Opportunity status to be updated (closed won or closed lost) when the opportunity's quote' status is changed to accepted or denied? I tried with workflow rules, but I didn't succeed, so I need some guidance on how should I do this.

- I also need the opportunity to not be closed won if there is more than one quotes available and open, even if one is accepted.

I am pretty new to Salesforce, so any help is welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this using [Flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow.htm&type=5), specifically a [record-triggered flow.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_trigger_record.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try process builder or flows.